# Create computer backup after crash

Tags: windows

I downloaded windows 11 preview ... attempted to run the eraser app and my computer crashed.

Windows Boot Manager appears; I tried the PCI LAN options , didn't work.  PKE over IPv4 and 6 don't work (not even completely sure what all that is but the only options I seem to have before I go straight to a new OS install)

Is there any way of attaching a different machine to recover data before I reinstall the OS?

Comment: See if you can start in Safe Mode after restarting the computer.  If not, you can use a bootable USB Key to recover your data.

Comment: Thanks John, I was not able to boot in safe mode but am now on the same pc using Ubuntu from a USB however, the Linux file system does not see any Users.  Under Other Locations there is a Windows Network but it says "unable to access location...no such file or directory."  Should I concede that my files are not recoverable?

Comment: You might be able to move the entire folder to a USB drive and then to a Windows computer and then see if you can take ownership of the files. That would be a way to recover them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the machine still boots, just Windows is destroyed,
perhaps the best way is to create a Linux Live USB and boot it to save
your data.

Next time, do not do a Windows 10 upgrade, or install a new and untried
system such as Windows 11, without taking very strong backups.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I am now on the same pc using Ubuntu from a USB however, the Linux file system does not see any Users.  Under Other Locations there is a Windows Network but it says "unable to access location...no such file or directory."  Should I concede that my files are not recoverable?

Comment: They are perhaps 90% sure of being lost. If you have a Windows boot media, you could as a last attempt boot to the Command Prompt and see if it can do any better (note that `C:` will then be the boot media, so the hard disk might be `D:`).

Comment: Yeah, looks like i'm not getting it back.   Now i'm having trouble reinstalling windows, haven't found a good article.  Wold you be able to offer any direction on installing windows on my pc while navigating from the Ubuntu usb? thx

Comment: Just google for "ubuntu create windows boot" and you will find several sources. I can't say which one is best.